# How to generate an OWIN bearer token during registration of a user

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin, bearer-token

I have implemented the authentication with OWIN and bearer token and it works fine when user tries to login. So I go to the special \Token url and provide username/password and get this token in response.
But I have a register user functionality as well and ideally I would like to get this token right away after I do register a user. I can go to the \Token internally in a web server, or do \Token after registration on the client, but I hope there is a solution where I can do something like

```
public Token RegisterUser(RegisterUserRequest request)
{
    // Registration here
    return OAuthProvider.GenerateToken(username, password)
}
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This took ages for me to figure out so I thought I'd add it here.

You can manually generate a token using the Protect function on AccessTokenFormat of your OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions object, assuming you've made it static in your startup class as otherwise it will be null.

```
AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties());
string token = Startup.OAuthServerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);
```

Seems a very odd place to put the token generation logic.

Anyway you can then do with the token as you wish, likely attach it to your outgoing header or response object.

Comment: Seems that this will really work, though you don't get the full formatted token data, but rather just the token itself. Though you have to add static property to the Startup for this  to work, and as you said it seems a very weird place to put the Protect method. Did you find anything better to generate full token data like '/Token' would do?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing you were, but I couldn't find anything, so I just made the request internally. Not very much work, but still a little disappointing.

```
public JToken GetLoginResponse(UserSignupDto dto)
{
    var tokenPath = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/token";
    var reqData = string.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}&client_id={2}", dto.Email, dto.Password, dto.ClientId);

    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
        return JObject.Parse(client.UploadString(tokenPath, reqData));
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not think of this solution, but I instead do two calls from the browser, first to register (I have the username and password at this point) and when it succeeds, I do call the Token. So it's almost the same, but you do it on the web server, I did it in the js. But it's strange that there is no good way around it.

Comment: anyone knows the way around to actually get token in the code?